# Is there any way to tell an x86 to discard dirty cache lines without writing them?

Tags: assembly, x86-64, cpu-cache

On a modern x86 with a large L3 cache it is entirely possible that I will write a block of data into L3 cache, then read it,  and then never access it again. I would like to free the space it occupies in cache without writing it back to memory (since RAM bandwidth is a limiting constraint for my application).
I know that overwriting it before it is written will work, but that only helps if I have some useful data ready to overwrite it with.

Is there any way to just tell the CPU that I don't care about the contents of those addresses any more?

Comment: Short answer is, I don't think so. You can configure the whole cache as ram, but that's probably not what you want. You could also try mapping nonexistent physical memory but no idea if that would work. Certainly if your cache line is evicted data will be lost.

Comment: You can discard the entire contents of the cache with `INVD`, but I don’t think that’s what you want, either.

Comment: If a device (a NIC or storage device, for example) writes those lines, it will cause the dirty CPU caches to be discarded.

Comment: No, there's AFAIK no way to break coherency and discard dirty data except `invd` which is basically unusable because it applies to *all* caches across all cores, not an address range.  If the data was clean you could `clflushopt` each line, but since it's probably dirty that would cost the DRAM bandwidth you want to avoid.

Comment: If possible, try "cache blocking" to use a smaller buffer in multiple passes, or keep using that same buffer for something else so it just stays hot in L3.